# What kind of lichen is it (no. 2)?

Tags: species-identification, mycology, algae

I think i found very interesting lichen. I discoved it at 1.15 PM CET in Prague nature conservation area called Divoka Sarka.

[image]

I took this picture on the place of my discovery.[image]

One piece of this specious had cca. 6 cm. And it look like a shrub.
[image]
And this is micro photograf with magnification about 200X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [fruiticose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruticose_lichen) lichen, meaning one with a bushy growth habit. They are common in my native state of Texas (USA), where they hang off of oak trees. Your photos look much like them. I have seen other examples in the rainforests of the Pacific Northwest, in both Oregon and Washington. I can't name the species.

In the upper left of your first photo, I see a thick, stem-like structure. This looks to me like the holdfast, the place the lichen attaches to the tree or other support.

Comment: i know it is hard to try find with this information something more then your answer mister. Of course i know that my discoveri can be put into fruiticose lichen, but i hope for much more accurate answer here. But u know the fruiticose lichen is more often on trees. This one was on the ground and thats fascinated me ! Even more fruiticose lichen is usually pollutation intolerant and i found it in the capital city of Czechia. And u know maybe it not even lichen, but dead moss, shrub. But still thank you :)